# Calculate no of fields in MYSQL between two data types

Tags: php, mysql

OK weird question.

Table consists of multiple fields.  Some with data type int(5) and the rest with datatype int(11)

So lets take a row...

```
id =>int(5)
var1 =>int(11)
var2 =>int(11)
var3 =>int(11)
var4 =>int(11)
var5 =>int(5)
var6 =>int(11)
var7 =>int(11)
var8 =>int(11)
```

How can I count the fields in PHP BETWEEN id (int(5)) and var (int(5))
I need to return the values in the fields between using php... but Im stuck.  Bad table design doesnt help...but Im stuck with it.

The full scenario is that i need to create an if statement which says, output the name and and data of the int(5) field IF any of the fields between it and the next int(5) contain data

sorry... ugly I know!!!

If run this so far

```
    $sql2 = 'SHOW COLUMNS from services2';
    $result2 = getDBResults($sql2, $level, $testing);

    $total = count($result2);


    $i=2;
    while ($i<($total-1))
    {
        $data = $result2[$i]['Field'];

        if ($result2[$i][1]=='int(5)')
        {
            $html .= '<h2>'.preg_replace('/(?<!\ )[A-Z]/', ' $0', $result2[$i]['Field']).'</h2>';
        }
        else
        {   
            ];
            // "$result - This is a seperate query run previously to get the row
            if ($result[0][$data] == 1)
            {
                $html .= '<p>'.preg_replace('/(?<!\ )[A-Z]/', ' $0', $data).'</p>';
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: you intend to do this in PHP?, if this is an array then use some of PHP's array functions, slice/splice accordingly, make an attempt.

Comment: telling me to make an attempt is about as useful as a chocloate fireguard.

States Im using PHP... so why the question.

Ive already written various array parsing scripts to obtain the field names and types along with associated data... Im asking the question to gain leverage on how people may tackle the issue!

Comment: why? what's wrong from making an attempt? its okay to make mistakes, thats why we are here to help. slice from start point to end point, count the remaining excluding the start and end (from an array sense).

Comment: Before I attempt an unnecessary answer, have you tried running a `DESCRIBE tablename` query to get you a list of the column names and data types?

Comment: Thank you... yes.  Currently the badlt tabularised data contains 'Titles' in the int(5) fields and data in the int(11) fields.

By using a similar approach and getting the MYSQL response, ive been able to format the output correctly, But I need to write a conditional which says... Output the TITLE if the data in the following int(11) fields contains data.   as opposed to out put it regardless! Hope that makes sense

Comment: @Ghost ... Agreed, but Im not the type to post when Im getting somewhere... I post when Ive hit a brink wall!  Not everyone posts on here looking for their code to be written for them.

Comment: yeah sorry... realised and hit the wrong button!

Comment: Out of curiosity though, what's the meaning of those fields in between the `int(5)` fields? And why don't you already know the position of the fields, because it's already in your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

I have not had a chance to actually test this, so dont beat me up if you need to tweek it a bit to smooth off any rough edges.

But its a fairly standard, if not totally simple, process of processing over the column names result array in a loop and just remembering the last int(5) column name in a variable so you can use it, if and only if, you have found some data in any int(11) column types before seeing the next int(5) column type.

*Now I understand why you had trouble explaining what you wanted, I am having the same trouble describing a solution.*

Anyway, have a look at this code and see if it makes any sence to you.

```
$sql2 = 'SHOW COLUMNS from services2';
$columns = getDBResults($sql2, $level, $testing);

$total = count($columns);

$print_column = null;
$found_data = false;

foreach ( $columns as $idx => $column ) {
    // skip first 2 columns
    if ($idx < 3 ) { continue; }

    // first time thru loop so remember the first int5 column name we saw
    if ( $column['Type'] == 'int(5)' && empty($print_column) ) {
        $print_column = $column['Field'];
        $found_data   = false;
        continue;
    }

    // found the next int5 column, do we need to print anything
    if ( $column['Type'] == 'int(5)' && $found_data ) {

        // This is where you would do any output creation, 
        // I just kept it simple.
        echo $result[0][$print_column];

        // reset state and the next field that might be printed.
        $found_data = false;
        $print_column = $column['Field'];
        continue;
    }

    // This may not need to be an if, but just in case you have other field types
    // that you are not interested in processing I made it an if.
    if ( $column['Type'] == 'int(11)' && ! empty($result[0][$column['Field']]) ) {
        $found_data = true;
    }

} // endforeach
```